# Error adding VividCortex angular-recaptcha dependency to AngularJS module

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I'm trying to add Google reCaptcha v2 to my AngularJS app. I'm trying to use VividCortex's angular-recaptcha, but I just can't add the dependency to my app module.

The original code of my module is something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.config(['$httpProvider','jwtInterceptorProvider', function Config($httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {
  //do stuff
}])

.config([ '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    //do other stuff
}])

.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['API_KEY', function(API_KEY) {
    //do more stuff
}]);
```

I've been trying to add the dependency like it's on the documentation:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['vcRecaptcha'])
```

But it gives me this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: jwtInterceptorProvider

I don't get this error if I don't try to add the dependency.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My lack of knowledge in AngularJS made me think that was where the module was being created, but it was just being retrieved, so when I was adding the dependency I was creating it again without the jwtInterceptor dependency, and so the error message.
I found where the module is created, added the dependency and now it's working.